# ¿Como puedo consumir un web services de datos json(XML) en php u en otro servicio?

Tags: php, json, xml, webservice, rest

[image: Datos Json (XML)]

Estoy buscando ayuda, pero no encuentro mucha información sobre el tema de consumir una web services con datos XML(JSON) con php.
Estaba pensandolo hacer así para tenerlo en un array e imprimirlo.

[image: DATOS]

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/107347), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878/107347). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

puedes usar curl php o este metodo sencillo:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($urlServicio),true); // Devuelve null en caso de error
```

en $url api le pasas la url del servicio que quieres consumir. 
te devolvera un objeto asociativo. 
para acceder a los datos hacer: $obj['p1ID'];